# ERC-20 Token Smart Contract Redeployment

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, etherscan, openzeppelin-contracts

Hello everyone am wondering how can someone redeploy ERC-20 Token Smart contract thats already deployed?

I have already deployed few contracts both on Ropsten Test Network and on Main ETH Network was sucessful in both instances, having that said all contracts I wrote from scratch that have values shown clearly, I mean by this:
- Name
- Total supply
- Symbol
- Decimals

Using Sublime to edit the contract then dropping it into Remix to compile and deploy it using web3 injected wallet such as Metamask.

I am trying to redeploy a smart contract thats already on the Main ETH network. Where is the total supply value? Why Values are not showing in the Smart Contract, Where should I edit?

There are many answers online but none of them gives clear answer to this!

Smart Contract code from Etherscan:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract SafeMath {
  function safeMul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a * b;
    assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    return c;
  }

  function safeDiv(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal returns (uint256) {
    assert(b > 0);
    uint256 c = a / b;
    assert(a == b * c + a % b);
    return c;
  }

  function safeSub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }

  function safeAdd(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    assert(c>=a && c>=b);
    return c;
  }

  function assert(bool assertion) internal {
    if (!assertion) {
      throw;
    }
  }
}
contract ERC20 is SafeMath{           
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    address public owner;

    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => uint256) public freezeOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    event Freeze(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    event Unfreeze(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    function ERC20(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string tokenName,
        uint8 decimalUnits,
        string tokenSymbol
        ) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              // Give the creator all initial tokens
        totalSupply = initialSupply;                        // Update total supply
        name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
        decimals = decimalUnits;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    /* Send coins */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        if (_to == 0x0) throw;                               // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        if (_value <= 0) throw; 
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;           // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw; // Check for overflows
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = SafeMath.safeSub(balanceOf[msg.sender], _value);                     // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] = SafeMath.safeAdd(balanceOf[_to], _value);                            // Add the same to the recipient
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);                   // Notify anyone listening that this transfer took place
    }

    /* Allow another contract to spend some tokens in your behalf */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value)
        returns (bool success) {
        if (_value <= 0) throw; 
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        return true;
    }


    /* A contract attempts to get the coins */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (_to == 0x0) throw;                                // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        if (_value <= 0) throw; 
        if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) throw;                 // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw;  // Check for overflows
        if (_value > allowance[_from][msg.sender]) throw;     // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] = SafeMath.safeSub(balanceOf[_from], _value);                           // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] = SafeMath.safeAdd(balanceOf[_to], _value);                             // Add the same to the recipient
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] = SafeMath.safeSub(allowance[_from][msg.sender], _value);
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function burn(uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;            // Check if the sender has enough
        if (_value <= 0) throw; 
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = SafeMath.safeSub(balanceOf[msg.sender], _value);                      // Subtract from the sender
        totalSupply = SafeMath.safeSub(totalSupply,_value);                                // Updates totalSupply
        Burn(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function freeze(uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;            // Check if the sender has enough
        if (_value <= 0) throw; 
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = SafeMath.safeSub(balanceOf[msg.sender], _value);                      // Subtract from the sender
        freezeOf[msg.sender] = SafeMath.safeAdd(freezeOf[msg.sender], _value);                                // Updates totalSupply
        Freeze(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function unfreeze(uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (freezeOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;            // Check if the sender has enough
        if (_value <= 0) throw; 
        freezeOf[msg.sender] = SafeMath.safeSub(freezeOf[msg.sender], _value);                      // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = SafeMath.safeAdd(balanceOf[msg.sender], _value);
        Unfreeze(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    // transfer balance to owner
    function withdrawEther(uint256 amount) {
        if(msg.sender != owner)throw;
        owner.transfer(amount);
    }

    // can accept ether
    function() payable {
    }
}
```

Comment: `Where is the total supply value?` - on the blockchain (where else?).

Answer (score 2):

When you deploy a contract with Remix (and any client capable of deploying a contract) you need to give the contract the required constructor arguments. In your case the required arguments are:

```
uint256 initialSupply,
string tokenName,
uint8 decimalUnits,
string tokenSymbol
```

These values can be given only when deploying the contract and therefore only once. If the contract doesn't have an empty constructor (as your contract doesn't) then you can't deploy it without providing values for these arguments. So just provide the correct values and they get stored in the contract when it's deployed successfully.